# Design patterns: Should repetitive function calls, to different modules, be moved to their own "abstraction"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, abstraction, single-responsibility-principle

As a JS developer i often find my self struggling with the question, whether certain "procedures" should be moved to their own layer. For example:

```
const localStorageUser = jwtService.userExistsInStorage();//Returns a user object if available
if (localStorageUser) {//If so, "login" from it
    // debugger;
    store.dispatch(userActions.setUserData(localStorageUser))//Set the user object in the Redux store.
    AjaxService.setHeader('token', localStorageUser.data.token);//Set the token header for every ajax request.

    if (localStorageUser.data.shortcuts) {
        store.dispatch(navigationActions.setNavigation(localStorageUser.data.shortcuts));
    } else {
        store.dispatch(navigationActions.resetNavigation());
    }
}
```

This is some code from a top-level file in a React app. As you can see, it calls various functions on initialization, when the app loads.

Let's say, that i might find my self one day repeating this code, in a different part of the app(some automatic re-login). Is it "customary" to put such code in its own class? I mean, **doing so would totally violate the Single responsibility principle**, being that this class/module would be highly coupled with many other classes and responsibilities.

This is just one example(perhaps not the best one), but this dilemma arises often. How do experienced developers approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acronym DRY - don't repeat yourself - say's it all. And extracting the code fit's the single-responsibility-principle perfectly, as the new class would be responsible for only one thing, the login process, and would only have one reason to change, namely if the login process changes. All other objects using the login component would not care (if the API does not change) which is what you want. Coupling creates a problem if you have to change the API of your component so always try to create clear and stable APIs.